# R plot graphs with large numbers

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using R and have an array with data values ranging from 600-225,000. I can plot it just fine, but the labels for the tick marks cover up the label for the axis.

Right now the code is:

```
g_range=range(0,list)
plot(list, axes=FALSE, ylab="Total")
axis(2, at=15000*0:g_range[2])
```

I just want to be able to see the values and the label

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem.  When I try to replicate your graph, the default `plot` axis seems just fine.  Have you perhaps passed some settings to `par`?  Try running your code again in a clean environment and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you more room, rotate the y-axis axis-labels 90 degrees and move the y-axis description out a line or two:

```
 #Generate the data
 list<-exp(seq(log(600), log(225000), length.out=10))
 g_range=range(0,list)

 #Setup the plotting area and plot it
 par(plt=c(0.2, 0.9, 0.2, 0.9))
 plot(list, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")

 #Plot the x-axis
 axis(1)
 mtext("Index", side=1, line=2)

 #Plot the y-axis     
 axis(2, las=2)
 mtext("Total", side=2, line=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `ggplot2` when I have a lot of values because it's easy to set the opacity of your dots. For example, this makes it so that you need 20 overlapping points to get a black spot. It's pretty neat. `ggplot2` also has sensible defaults for setting axis labels, so you shouldn't have to worry about it too much.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(150000), x2=rnorm(150000))
ggplot(dat, aes(x1,x2))+geom_point(alpha=0.05)
```

Comment: -1 Although your plot nicely illustrated `alpha`, I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: I have to say I'm not too happy about this. The question was far from clear, and it doesn't even provide a reproducible example. I went through the trouble of producing artificial data and plotted it. If the data doesn't look like the one from the problem, it clearly means I have not understood what the OP was asking. If the OP had asked a better question, maybe he would get better answers.

Comment: OK.  Maybe a downvote is a bit too harsh. I've reversed that.  I agree with you - the question isn't particularly clear.